# Show the sequence ${n^m + 1}\over {n^{m+1} + 1}$ with $m \in \mathbb{R}$ is decreasing

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence $\{a_n\}_1^\infty$ such that $ a_n = $  ${n^m + 1}\over {n^{m+1} + 1}$ and $m \in \mathbb{R}$

EDIT: This is incorrect for $m < -1$, Then add the condition $m \geq -1$

I want to show this sequence is monotonically decreasing.
This is not homework, I've seen many specific examples of this however and graphed many cases, and I'd like to show this for the general case.

I've tried considering the continuous case and taking the derivative, using the quotient rule I get a square in the denominator, and since I'm only interested in the sign of the derivative I can throw away the denominator in the quotient rule, I then have:

$mx^{m-1}(x^{m+1} + 1) - (m+1)x^m(x^m + 1)$

Plugging in $x = 1$ gives a negative result for the derivative showing the continuous function is decreasing at that point, so I get a feeling my "conjecture" is correct. 
Not sure where I can go from here, and if there's a simpler way without going to the continuous case.
Expanding the brackets didn't help much either

Comment: When $m$ is positive integer then this is almost obvious. When $n$ increases the change in $n^{m + 1}$ is more than that in $n^{m}$ and this makes the sequence $a_{n}$ decrease when increasing $n$. Also if $m < -1$ you will find that your sequence eventually starts increasing. So you need to change your question and add the condition $m + 1 \geq 0$.

Comment: You are right about $m < -1$ case. About when m is a positive integer, I see the changed in $n^{m+1}$ is bigger, but in the quotient rule I not only have the difference in derivatives, but each one also multiplies the other function? How would I prove that since $n^{m+1}$ grows faster then the sequence decreases?

Comment: @JonasMeyer You are right, I changed it, thank you

Comment: I reasoned in the following way (consider all numbers as positive). We have $a/b > (a + x)/(b + y)$ if $a / b > x / y$. Now here $a/b = (n^{m} + 1)/(n^{m + 1} + 1) \approx 1/n$ and $x / y = \Delta n^{m}/\Delta n^{m + 1} \approx mn^{m - 1}/(m + 1)n^{m} = m/(n(m + 1))$. As long as $m + 1 > 0$ we can see that $a / b > x / y$. This is sort of intuitive argument and a proper proof is through derivatives or inequalities (and both these approaches are given in answers already provided).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{n^m + 1}{n^{m+1} + 1} \geq \frac{(n+1)^m + 1}{(n+1)^{m+1} + 1} \Leftrightarrow \\
(n^m + 1)((n+1)^{m+1} + 1) \geq ((n+1)^m + 1)(n^{m+1} + 1)\Leftrightarrow \\
n^m (n+1)^{m+1} + n^m +(n+1)^{m+1} + 1\geq (n+1)^m n^{m+1} + (n+1)^m + n^{m+1} + 1 \Leftrightarrow \\
n^m (n+1)^{m}  +n(n+1)^{m} \geq n^m (n-1) \Leftrightarrow \\
 (n+1)^{m}  +n(1+\frac{1}{n})^{m} \geq  (n-1)$$

As $m \geq -1$ and the exponentials $(n+1)^x$ and $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{x}$ are increasing, we have

$$(n+1)^{m}  +n(1+\frac{1}{n})^{m} \geq (n+1)^{-1}  +n(1+\frac{1}{n})^{-1} = \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{n^2}{n+1}> \frac{n^2-1}{n+1}=n-1 $$

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer, I actually meant to write for $m \geq -1$ but that was my mistake. I'll leave it open for a bit more but will accept this answer if there isn't one for the more general case.

Comment: @avdorian I changed it a little so it works for $m >-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Take
$$
f(x) = \frac{x^m + 1}{x^{m+1} + 1}
$$

When you differentiate, your numerator should be 
$$
(x^{m+1} +1)mx^{m-1} - (x^m+1)(m+1)x^m = -x^{m-1}(x^{m+1} + (m+1)x - m)
$$
Now, $x^m + (m+1)x - m > 0$ for large values of $x$, so $a_n$ is *eventually* decreasing. However, a little checking with small values of $x$ should tell you that it is decreasing everywhere.

Comment: To Prahlad: The function will decrease only when $m + 1 \geq 0$ otherwise it will be an increasing function for large values of $x$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I am not sure how checking for specific values of x could tell me it is decreasing everywhere

Comment: To avdo rian: This is not a check for specific values of $x$, rather what is being mentioned here is that after a certain value of $x$ say $x = X_{0}$ the derivative $f'(x)$ is always negative for $x > X_{0}$ and hence the function $f(x)$ is decreasing for all $x > X_{0}$.